# What URL should I use in $.ajax() in order to submit a form

Tags: ajax, forms, url, jsf-2

Working in JSF2 and ajax, i can't figure out what's the value of the $.ajax URL attribute in JSF context as i want to submit a form and update a div staying in the same page

Is it the following?

```
((HttpServletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest()).getContextPath()`
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you need pass value to the backing bean and set the parameter, after this you need to update this part (div).

see this http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/

```
        <p:commandButton action="#{bean.setId}" update="div">
            <f:attribute name="id" value="12" />             
        </p:commandButton>
```

Another way is using flash, see this: https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/context/Flash.html

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a form like this:

```
<div id="yourDivId">
    <h:outputText value='#{yourControllerClass.yourAttribute}'></h:outputText>
</div>
<h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="update">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{yourControllerClass.updateAttribute}" 
                        render=":yourDiveId">
                </f:ajax>
        </h:commandButton>

</h:form>
```

in your ControllerClass/bean:

```
public final void updateAttribute(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    // do what ever you want, get values, set another values, after that your Div will be auto updated
}
```

this way, you don't need to care about ajax params or URL...etc.

**EDIT:**

if you want to get a paramater from a request URL, then you can get it like this:

```
String paramVal = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(key);
```

Comment: great using f:ajx tag. How about trying to implement my own ajax handler class doing the same task as f:ajax? This whay i'm looking for knowing how JSF handles URL ajax attribute

Comment: @farouk, this is a complex approach, but if you want to get a param from the request URL, then see my update!

Comment: thanks Rami. It's so helpful. In other way, how i can pefrom a form submit in JSF2 without using f:ajax; to get the form parameter and send them to the FacesServlet, or we need something else ?

Comment: as working with JSP and Servlet all we neeed is the ID of the servlet int the action attribute in the form. Morever what ib should put the URL of the ajax statement ?